# How to Navigate to Pages on ListView ItemSelected while it is in other class file?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin

I am stuck on Navigating Pages in my app. I am beginner to Xamarin Form. What i am doing is  i have a Master Details Page called master.cs by default it navigates to home page i.e. content page. I have created list view in other class page i.e. ModelClasses.cs now i want to navigate to other content pages while select listview item. i tried lot more things but not working. 
HELP ME!!

**MasterPage**

```
public class master : MasterDetailPage
    {
        public master ()
        {
            Label header = new Label {
                Text = "Master",
                Font = Font.BoldSystemFontOfSize (20)
            };
            MenuStacklayout _MenuStacklayout = new MenuStacklayout ();
            this.Master = new ContentPage{ 
                Title=header.Text,
                Content=_MenuStacklayout
            };

            this.Detail = new NavigationPage(new FTWHome());

            // For Windows Phone, provide a way to get back to the master page.
            if (Device.OS == TargetPlatform.WinPhone)
            {
                (this.Detail as ContentPage).Content.GestureRecognizers.Add(
                    new TapGestureRecognizer((view) =>
                        {
                            this.IsPresented = true;
                        }));
            }
        }
    }
```

**ModelClasses**

***MenuStacklayout*** Creates a Menu

```
    public class MenuStacklayout : StackLayout
        {
            String[] homelinks = { "HOME" };
            String[] healthlinks = { "I NEED HELP", "A MATE NEEDS HELP", "MOOD TRACKER", "HELPFUL ARTICLES" };
            String[] entertainmentlinks = { "PHOTO OF THE DAY", "MAGZINE CONTENTS", "FTW TEAM" };
            String[] aboutlinks = { "FTW PHILOSOPHY", "ABOUT FTW", "FTW STORE", "FTW SOCIAL" };
            String[] joinftwlinks = { "JOIN FTW" };
            String[] loginlinks = { "LOGIN" };

            #region Menu Layout
            public MenuStacklayout ()
            {
                ListView homelist = new ListView { 
                    ItemsSource = menuitems._menuitems (homelinks),
                    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (typeof(ftwMenuCell))
                };
                homelist.RowHeight = 30;
                homelist.ItemSelected+= navigatePage_onSelected;
                StackLayout homeliststack = new StackLayout ();
                homeliststack.Children.Add (homelist);
                homelist.SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None;

                //homeliststack.Padding = new Thickness (2, 5, 0, 0);
                ListView healthlist = new ListView { 
                    //Header = "HEALTH",
                    ItemsSource = menuitems._menuitems (healthlinks),
                    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (typeof(ftwMenuCell))
                };
                healthlist.RowHeight = 30;
                healthlist.ItemSelected+=navigatePage_onSelected;
                StackLayout healthliststack = new StackLayout ();
                healthliststack.Children.Add (healthlist);
                healthlist.SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None;

                ListView entertainmentlist = new ListView { 
                    //Header = "ENTERTAINMENT",
                    ItemsSource = menuitems._menuitems (entertainmentlinks),
                    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (typeof(ftwMenuCell))
                };
                entertainmentlist.RowHeight = 30;
                entertainmentlist.ItemSelected+=navigatePage_onSelected;
                StackLayout entertainmentliststack = new StackLayout ();
                entertainmentliststack.Children.Add (entertainmentlist);
                entertainmentlist.SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None;

                ListView aboutlist = new ListView { 
                    //Header = "ABOUT",
                    ItemsSource = menuitems._menuitems (aboutlinks),
                    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (typeof(ftwMenuCell))
                };
                aboutlist.RowHeight = 30;
                aboutlist.ItemSelected+=navigatePage_onSelected;
                StackLayout aboutliststack = new StackLayout ();
                aboutliststack.Children.Add (aboutlist);
                aboutlist.SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None;

                ListView joinftwlist = new ListView { 
                    ItemsSource = menuitems._menuitems (joinftwlinks),
                    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (typeof(ftwMenuCell))
                };
                joinftwlist.RowHeight = 30;
                StackLayout joinftwliststack = new StackLayout ();
                joinftwliststack.Children.Add (joinftwlist);
                joinftwlist.SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None;

                ListView loginlist = new ListView { 
                    ItemsSource = menuitems._menuitems (loginlinks),
                    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate (typeof(ftwMenuCell))
                };
                loginlist.RowHeight = 30;
                loginlist.SeparatorVisibility = SeparatorVisibility.None;
                loginlist.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
                StackLayout loginstack = new StackLayout ();
                loginstack.Children.Add (loginlist);


                this.Spacing = 1;
                this.BackgroundColor = Color.FromHex("#cccccc");
                this.Padding = new Thickness (0, 65, 0, 0);
                this.Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical;
                this.VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.StartAndExpand;
                this.Children.Add (homeliststack);
                this.Children.Add (healthliststack);
                this.Children.Add (entertainmentliststack);
                this.Children.Add (aboutliststack);
                this.Children.Add (joinftwlist);
                this.Children.Add (loginstack);
            }
        }
```

***ItemTemplate For Menu***

```
public class ftwMenuCell : ViewCell
    {
        public ftwMenuCell ()
        {
            var nameLabel = new Label () {
                FontFamily = "HelveticaNeue-Medium",
                FontSize = 14,
                FontAttributes=FontAttributes.Bold,
                TextColor = Color.Black,
                VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.Center
            };
            nameLabel.SetBinding (Label.TextProperty, "_link");
            var cellLayout = new StackLayout {
                Spacing = 0,
                Padding = new Thickness (10, 0, 0, 0),
                VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                Children = { nameLabel }
            };

            this.View = cellLayout;
        }

    }

    public class _menulink
    {
        public string _link{ get; set; }
    }

    public static class menuitems
    {
        public static List<_menulink> _menuitems (string[] linkid)
        {
            List<_menulink> menulinklist = new List<_menulink> ();
            foreach (var item in linkid) {
                _menulink menulink = new _menulink ();
                menulink._link = item;
                menulinklist.Add (menulink);
            }
            return menulinklist;
        }
    }
```

i have respective content page for Every Listview Item. 
THANKS IN ADVANCE!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it !!

in my navigatePage_onSelected event handler which is declared in MenuStacklayout Class i put following code and it's working.

```
void navigatePage_onSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs args){
            _menulink menuitem = (_menulink)args.SelectedItem;
            MasterDetailPage mstr = (MasterDetailPage)(Application.Current.MainPage); // My Application main page is a Masterpage so..
            if (menuitem._link == "ABOUT FTW") {
                mstr.Detail = new NavigationPage (new AboutFTW ());
            }else if(menuitem._link == "I NEED HELP"){
                mstr.Detail = new NavigationPage (new Entertainment ());
            }else if(menuitem._link == "HOME"){
                mstr.Detail = new NavigationPage (new FTWHome ());
            }
            // Show the detail page.
            mstr.IsPresented = false;
        }
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution though I have one comment.  NavigationPages are typically used as a hub to go to other pages. I can't see the code for your pages so I could be wrong but it seems like these are destination pages.  If that is the case you may want to use a ContentPage.  This isn't really that important but I thought I'd mention it :)

Comment: @I_Khanage yes, mentioned navigation pages are my destination pages where my other stuffs written.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you *navigatePage_onSelected* is declared but you could try something like

```
void navigatePage_onSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) {
    Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PageName());
}
```

Let me know if that works out for you :)

Comment: yap not given but it is there in my solution. And will try and let you know. and thanks i was waiting who is giving me some idea.

Comment: not working it's wrong statement .Navigation.PushModalAsync(new PageName());